# Session "flash data" not working?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to imitate the flashdata behavior for displaying one-time error messages.

This displays the page:

```
public function showLoginAndRegistrationPage()
{
    $session = new Session();
    $data['errors']['login'] = $session->getFormErrorFlashData('login', 'account');
    $this->viewPresenter->display('basic', 'customer/login-registration', $data, 'Login/Register');
}
```

This is the processing:

```
public function processLogin()
{
    // Some code

    if($this->formInputFilter->isValid()) {
        // Some code

        if($loginCredentials) {
            // Some code
        } else {
            $errors = array(
                'account' => 'Account does not exist.'
            );
            $session->setFormErrorFlashData('login', $errors);

            header('Location: /login');
        }
    } else {
       // Some code
    }
}
```

Set flash data, inside `Session` class:

```
public function setFormErrorFlashData($form, $errors = array())
{
    foreach($errors As $field => $message) {
        $_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]["{$field}"] = $message;
    }
}
```

Display flash data, inside `Session` class:

```
public function getFormErrorFlashData($form, $field)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]["{$field}"])) {
        $message = $_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]["{$field}"];
        unset($_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]);

        return $message;
    }
}
```

`$data['errors']['login']` in `showLoginAndRegistrationPage()` should display 'Account does not exist' in the view after an invalid login attempt but it doesn't. I've used `var_dump()` and it's always `NULL`.

In `showLoginAndRegistrationPage()`, `$data['errors']['login']` always comes up empty. I've checked in the `else` block in `processLogin()` and `setFormErrorFlashData()` does work. I used `var_dump()` right after setting it to check, and it does return the data. It's just that after an invalid attempt, after I redirect to `showLoginAndRegistrationPage()` I'm not getting anything.

**UPDATE:**

```
public static function getFormErrorFlashData($form, $field)
{
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    var_dump($form, $field);
    if(isset($_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]["{$field}"])) {
        $message = $_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]["{$field}"];
        unset($_SESSION['errors']["{$form}"]);

        return $message;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
// No attempts yet
array(1) { ["errors"]=> array(0) { } } string(5) "login" string(7) "account"

// After 1 invalid attempt
array(1) { ["errors"]=> array(0) { } } string(5) "login" string(7) "account"

// RESULT FROM ADDING: 
// die(var_dump($session->getFormErrorFlashData('login','account'))); 
// after setFormErrorFlashData() inside the else block

array(1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["login"]=> array(1) { ["account"]=> string(23) "Account does not exist." } } } string(5) "login" string(7) "account" string(23) "Account does not exist."
```

Comment: It may help if you are able to show the var_dump($_SESSION) and the values of $form and $field when calling.

Comment: @AlexBarker I updated my question.

Comment: @AlexBarker Before the unset, the correct message is being returned by `$message`. It seems that once you reach the `unset()` line, all the other variables that held that  value even if they were called before the unset end up empty.